# Pass function to setTimeout via fn.apply or fn.bind

Tags: javascript, node.js

In order to throttle requests to APIs, I've made a method that only allows a certain amount of requests per interval.

It works, but I'd like to feinschmecker the `setTimeout` part.

I've tried `setTimeout(fn.apply, self.sleepTime(), null, fn_arguments)` and `setTimeout(fn.bind(fn_arguments), self.sleepTime())`.

So what I would like to know is if I can pass `fn` to `setTimeout` without wrapping it in a `function`?

```
function (fn) {
  var self = this;
  return function () {
    var fn_arguments = arguments;
    setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(null, fn_arguments);
    }, self.sleepTime());
  };
};
```

### Test:

```js
var args;

function fn () {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(arguments), ' ~ ', JSON.stringify(arguments) === JSON.stringify(args));
  document.write('<br>');
}

(function() {
  args = arguments;
  fn('hello', 'world'); // { '0': 'hello', '1': 'world' }  ✓
  fn.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(arguments))(); // { '0': { '0': 'hello', '1': 'world' } }
  fn.bind.apply(fn, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))(); // { '0': 'world' }
  fn.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))(); // { '0': 'hello', '1': 'world' }  ✓
}('hello', 'world'));
```

Comment: You'd like to what now?

Comment: Can I pass `fn` to `setTimeout` without wrapping it in a `function`?

Comment: Not if you want to include arguments like that. I've never seen "feinschmecker" in the spec, what operation on a function is that, exactly?

Comment: feinschmecker is slang for improve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! You just need to combine the 2nd and 3rd steps:

```
fn.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind to create a function which contains the function arguments and use it in the setTimout call. However, bind does not take a single array of arguments, but multiple, comma separated arguments. To fix this, you can call apply on the bind function, like this:

```
setTimeout(fn.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(fn_arguments)), self.sleepTime())
```

*edit:* You have to make sure that `fn_arguments` is an array, e.g. by converting the arguments object via `var fn_arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: Sorry, I can not get that to work. Check the runnable code snippet I added above. Your answer gives me `{"0":{"0":"hello","1":"world"}}`

Comment: You have to make sure that `fn_arguments` is an array. Passing the arguments object does not work. In your example code, use `fn.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))();`